# Maven how to exclude dependecy which appears multiple times

Tags: maven

I'd like to know if there is a way to exclude sdk-s3 just one time. I want to do it because I don't use it and also maven for some reason, starts downloading all the sdk-s3 versions and takes a long time to finish.

Is there a way to exlude this dependecy globally? Thanks

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-sqs</artifactId>
    <version>1.11.591</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-sts</artifactId>
    <version>1.11.591</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.11.591</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no *real* way to exclude a dependency globally. You can set the scope of the dependency to `provided` in `<dependencyManagement>`. This makes sure that the dependency will not be included in the resulting war or ear. It will still be on the compile classpath, though. You could also use the scope `test` for that.

This scope based approach is of course not what the developers of Maven intended.

Note furthermore, that Maven downloads dependencies only once and caches them in the local repository afterwards. If you want to avoid to have multiple versions, you can fix one version in the `<dependencyManagement>`.

Answer (score 0):

As @JF Meier said, there is no real way to exclude it from all the transitive dependencies.

If the problem is that it's causing a conflict with another version of the same dependency, you override this, but explicitly defining the dependency with the version that you're interested in. This way, as it will be higher in the hierarchy, you can override all the transitive dependencies from where it's coming.

Comment: Usually, for overriding versions, I would use `<dependencyManagement>`.

Comment: Absolutely! :)
However, sometimes you might have a dependency coming from multiple transitivie dependencies each bringing a different version of it and sometimes fixing the mess might be easier with a more brutal approach like defining the dependency explicitly higher up in the dependency graph.

Comment: But, `<dependencyManagement>` already overrides all transitive dependencies. What is the advantage of using an explicit dependency?

Comment: You mean if you define the dependency (that you want to be excluding) under a `<dependencyManagement/>` section?

Comment: I mean that if I want `aws-java-sdk-s3` in version `2.0` throughout my transitive dependencies, I would add an entry to the `dependencyManagement` section and would _not_ define `aws-java-sdk-s3` as direct dependency (unless, of course, I also use it directly in my source code).

Comment: I was actually referring to the case where several different dependencies could be bringing different versions of `aws-java-sdk-s3`. This is often the case for things like `commons-io`, `commons-logging` and so on (in large codebases this is quite possible and often causes a mess and defining exclusions for each of them one by one might be a massive pain compared to just defining the dependency with the particular version that you'd like to enforce)...

Comment: I am talking about the very same thing. If you have various versions of `commons-io` in your transitive dependencies, just put one `<dependencyManagement>` entry for `commons-io` into your project (with the version you desire). This replaces all transitive versions with this version. You do not need to add a direct dependency.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201113/discussion-between-carlspring-and-jf-meier).

Comment: With Java 9 modules, it would be great to tell Maven always exclude, for example, `xml-apis` because you always want to use the JRE/JDK version, even (especially) at compile time.  It's a royal pain in the, um, neck to exclude it from every 3rd party dependency that pulls it in (including all the transitive ones you might never refer to directly otherwise).  This seems to be an Eclipse disease and it might be worth dealing with IntelliJ for this reason.